# seaborn place value into bar itself

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart, seaborn

Is it possible to place value into bar itself?

For example place numbers 1-4 on centers of  these bars.
This bar chart is from searborn examples.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [matplotlib.pyplot.text](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text)

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips) 
ax.text( -0.1, 10, '1', fontsize=24)
ax.text(1-0.1, 10, '2', fontsize=24)
ax.text(2-0.1, 10, '3', fontsize=24)
ax.text(3-0.1, 10, '4', fontsize=24)
```

[image]